# Twice Ringing state indication and no idle/offhook state indication in android

Tags: android

When I try to monitor the phone state, only ringing state is passed by. The other two states, idle and offhook are never seen whenever the incoming call is answered, rejected or timeout. And there are two ringings indicated for one incoming call. That is so strange. List the run log for one incoming call which phone number is 02xxxxxxxxx for example:

---

D/INCOMING: 02xxxxxxxxx

D/oriRingtone: 1

D/State: RINGING

D/AudioManager: setStreamVolume(streamType:2, index:7, flags:6)

D/INCOMING: 02xxxxxxxxx

D/oriRingtone: 2

D/State: RINGING

D/AudioManager: setStreamVolume(streamType:2, index:7, flags:6)

I add the permisson and register the phone state change in BroadcastReceiver.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
```

And

```
    <receiver android:name=".PhoneCallHandler">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I wonder why there are two Ringing indications and how to get idle and offhook state to be infored. Thanks.

List code for info:

```
public class PhoneCallHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {
static boolean flag = false;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String phoneNumber = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
        Log.d("INCOMING", phoneNumber);

        String state = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        //Log.d("ACTION", action);

        AudioManager auManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int oriRingtone = auManager.getRingerMode();
        Log.d("oriRingtone", String.valueOf(oriRingtone));
        Log.d("State", state);

        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            switch (phoneNumber) {
                case "02584929790":
                    auManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 7, AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES | AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
                    break;
            }
        }else{
            auManager.setRingerMode(oriRingtone);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

BroadcastReceiver

```
`public class IncommingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

        int state = 0;
        if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;


        } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;



        } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;


        }

    }
}`
```

Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".IncommingCallReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thanks,Siddhesh. My code is similar with you. But I didn't see IDLE and OFFHOOK state. Do you know how to get those state?

Comment: if missed call then-> Ringing-> idle, if answer call then call-> Ringing->offhook->idle ,if cut call then-> ringing-> idle.

Comment: But I never seen these state transaction in logs and in code execution result. Do you know how? I list my code for your info.

Comment: for testing which device you are using?

Comment: I use HTC D826w

Comment: try in emulator